# expected ';' after top level declarator, error in VS Code

Tags: c++, arrays, macos, visual-studio-code

I try to run this code on my mac:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
using namespace std;

const size_t rows{2};
const size_t columns{3};

int main() {
    array<array<int, columns>, rows> array1{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}};
    array<array<int, columns>, rows> array2{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}};

    cout << "Values in array1 by row are:" << endl;
    printArray(array1);

    cout << "\nValues in array2 by row are:" << endl;
    printArray(array2);
}

void printArray(const array<array<int, columns>, rows>& a) {
    for (auto const& row : a) {
        for (auto const& element : row) {
            cout << element << ' ';
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

There're errors on a line that use array. For example:

```
const size_t rows{2};
```

said "expected ';' after top level declarator" even though I already put a semicolon.

```
array<array<int, columns>, rows> array1{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}};
```

said "non-type template argument of type 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') is not an integral constant expression" at 'columns' and 'expected ';' at end of declaration' at array1

I tried to run the same program on another computer and it worked normally but mine just always stuck at this error.
What causes the problem and how to resolve it?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Add `-std=c++11` or newer to the compiler options.

Comment: by default Macs compile to the 1998 C++ Standard. There's probably a reason for that default, but, in general, wow. A nasty surprise to a lot of people learning C++ from modern resources.

Comment: You'll likely need to update tasks.json AND ... <expletive deleted>. I can't remember the name of the other json file. The first tells the compiler what to do. The second, the one I can't remember, tells the code analysis tool what to do so it can put the red squiggles in the right spots. Only changing one of them is a common source of frustration.

Comment: @user4581301 c_cpp_properties.json. I've recently decided to give VSCode another go, God it is awful.

Comment: @john it depends how you use it, if you use it to compile c++ code without using a build system then yes it's fiddly to configure, but so would any other text editor be that you compile your code with bash scripts. Used with a build system, especially one like cmake that has a plugin that automatically configures intellisense it's a reasonably good ide

Comment: @AlanBirtles Using the cmake extension is what persuaded me to give VSCode another go. But it seems like every possible setting has a default different from what I would prefer. Plus the GUI for changing settings is clunky. I'm hoping I'll get it set up in a way I can live with eventually but it's taking a while.